# Mypy type narrowing from assertion

Tags: python, mypy

I have two variables `a` and `b` that are either `int` or `str`.
I write an assertion that insists `a` and `b` are either both ints or strs.

If I typenarrow `a` to an int, is there a way for mypy to infer `b` is also an int?
Here is some sample code.

Mypy version:

```
mypy 0.980+dev.0f17aff06ac1c05c442ba989e23655a2c6adbfbf (compiled: no)
```

Thanks for your help.

```
def my_func(a: int | str, b: int | str):
    # We assert one of the statements is true: 1) a and b are ints, or 2) a and b are strings.
    # In the case of an int a, and a string b, or vice versa, this assertion will fail.
    assert isinstance(a, int) == isinstance(b, int)
    # Another alternative assertion
    assert type(a) == type(b)

    if isinstance(a, int):
        reveal_type(b)  # mypy still thinks b is int or str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', int, str)


def reveal_type(a: int):
    pass


def foo(a: str):
    pass


def my_func(a: T, b: T):
    if isinstance(a, int):
        reveal_type(b)  # pass
    else:
        foo(b)          # pass
```

If we simply exchange the calling positions of the two functions, mypy will find that they are all wrong calls and give two errors:

```
def my_func(a: T, b: T):
    if isinstance(a, int):
        foo(b)          # Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" (16:12)
    else:
        reveal_type(b)  # Argument 1 to "reveal_type" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" (18:20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't quite seem to work. Mypy doesn't actually infer the type correctly in either branch. In the first branch, mypy thinks the type of  `b` is `T@my_func`. Pyright also complains.

Comment: Also, adding `foo(b)` to the first branch incorrectly passes.

Comment: @hwong557 Simply exchange the calling positions of `reveal_type` and `foo`, and my mypy will give me two errors: `Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" (16:12)`, `Argument 1 to "reveal_type" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" (18:20)`, they show that both branches mypy have made correct judgments.